# Binary Tree Searh Check

Tags: python-3.x

NameError: name 'tree' is not defined

Hello everyone,
I am working on a BST Check (Binary Search Tree Check) problem and I do not get the expected result which should be 'True'. My code can be found below. Whenever I compile it with VScode, it says: name 'tree' is not defined.
Can you help me with it please?
Thanks forward!

```
 tree_vals = []

 def inorder(tree):
     if tree != None:
     inorder(tree.getLeftChild())
     tree_vals.append(tree.getRootVal())
     inorder(tree.getRightChild())

 def sort_check(tree_vals):
     return tree_vals == sorted(tree_vals)


 inorder(tree)  
 print(sort_check(tree_vals))
```

Comment: I don't see any `tree` variable instantiation.

Comment: Where is `tree` defined in your code? Did you intentionally omit it here?

Comment: Yes, I did intentionally